# R: collapse rows and then convert row into a new column

Tags: r

So here is my challenge. I am trying to get rid of rows of data that are best organized as a column. The original data set looks like

```
1|1|a
2|3|b
2|5|c
1|4|d
1|2|e
10|10|f
```

And the end result desired is

```
1 |1,2,4 |a| e d
2 |3,5   |b| c
10|10    |f| NA
```

The table's shaping is based from minimum value Col 2 within groupings of Col 1, where new column 3 is defined from the minimum values within the group and new column 4 is collapsed from not the minimum of. Some of the approaches tried include:

```
newTable[min(newTable[,(1%o%2)]),] ## returns the minimum of both COL 1 and 2 only

ddply(newTable,"V1", summarize, newCol = paste(V7,collapse = " ")) ## collapses all values by Col 1 and creates a new column nicely.
```

Variations to combine these lines of code into a single line have not worked, in part to my limited  knowledge. These modifications are not included here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

 dat %>% 
     group_by(V1) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(paste(sort(.), collapse=","))) %>%
     extract(V3, c("V3", "V4"), "(.),?(.*)")
```

gives the output

```
  #  V1    V2 V3  V4
  #1  1 1,2,4  a d,e
  #2  2   3,5  b   c
  #3 10    10  f
```

Or using `aggregate` and `str_split_fixed`

```
 res1 <- aggregate(.~ V1, data=dat, FUN=function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=","))
 library(stringr)
 res1[, paste0("V", 3:4)] <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(res1$V3, ",", 2), 
                                              stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If you need `NA` for missing values

```
  res1[res1==''] <- NA
  res1
  # V1    V2 V3   V4
 #1  1 1,2,4  a  d,e
 #2  2   3,5  b    c
 #3 10    10  f <NA>
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L), V2 = c(1L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 10L), V3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Very functional. For future users in this situation. If V1 and V2 are numerical, R 3.1.1 will return "Error: length(n) == 1 is not TRUE". In order to function, the numbers must be an Integer variable. Appreciate the assist!

Comment: @Aaron I am using `R 3.1.0`.  I guess you were able to fix the error by converting to `integer`..

Comment: I ran the code on another data set with numeric columns, and then -yes-  converted them from numeric class to integer. It worked nicely. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using `data.table`, with data from @akrun's post:

It might be useful to store the columns as `list` instead of pasting them together.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
setDT(dat)[order(V1, V2), list(V2=list(V2), V3=V3[1L], V4=list(V3[-1L])), by=V1]
#    V1    V2 V3  V4
# 1:  1 1,2,4  a e,d
# 2:  2   3,5  b   c
# 3: 10    10  f
```

`setDT(dat)` converts the data.frame to data.table, by reference (without copying it). Then, we sort it by columns `V1,V2` and group by `V1` column on the sorted data, and for each group, we create the columns `V2`, `V3` and `V4` as shown.

`V2` and `V4` will be of type `list` here. If you'd rather have a character column where all entries are pasted together, just replace `list(.)` with `paste(., sep=...)`.

HTH